# Django website with email support

Tags: django, email

Im building a website for my first client :) . Its a simple website with the usual home, about us and contact pages which is a piece of cake to build. However, I need to add an industry standard email system to the website.

For example, if www.domain.com is the website then users will have email addresses like user@domain.com.

Its been just three months since I started learning web development, and I havent really dug deep into how emails work. I experimented a little with django's email framework but, im not sure how to receive emails and even if I did, I wouldnt be able to write a fully functional app.

So I looked through the email apps on djangopackages but, I am really not confident with about using them because I have to study and experiment before using.  So,
Im looking for an application or service like MS outlook to handle all the emails separately from the website. Are there any solutions? Am i thinking in the right direction? Whats the approach professionals use ?

Im deploying on webfaction.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Here's a tip: avoid using phrases like "industry standard email system" because there is no such thing. @Alasdair you should add your comment as an answer.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid why do you say there is no such thing as "industry standard email system"? Don't you think gmail, yahoo, etc are industry standard?

Comment: No, they are not. "Industry standard" is just marketing spam, used in brochures and by talking heads to make systems/services appear more "robust" than they are.  Each industry also has their own requirements. Its like saying there is an industry standard computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email is a separate service to the website. The email functionality built into Django is only for sending emails, not receiving them.

Since you're hosting with Webfaction, I would start off with their [email docs](http://docs.webfaction.com/user-guide/email.html). They contain instructions how to set up a mailbox on Webfaction, and how to configure your email client to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this simple Gmail plugin to your settings.py file for email testing.  All of your emails must be with gmail.  Here is the code:

```
# EMAIL Settings
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your_email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your_gmail_password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

You can test the above code snippet in your python shell with:

```
import django
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'gmail_address_to_send_from@gmail.com',
    ['gmail_address_to_send_to@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

If you want to have your email use the domain name of your site for the site your building then you need to sign up for email hosting with your web host, or any other email hosting service and configure it to your webserver using the MX Record settings accordingly with your web host.

Comment: This is not what the question is asking. He is not asking how to send email, he is asking how to receive email.